# Google Cloud Dataflow with Apache Beam does not display log

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-logging

My problem is that the logs on the dataflow does not display anything (monitoring api is enabled) and I have no idea why.

With the following Apache Beam code (adopted from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging),

```
import argparse
import logging
import re
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions
from apache_beam import FlatMap, Map, Pipeline


def run(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input",
        dest="input",
        default="gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt",
        help="Input file to process.",
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        filtered_words = (
            p
            | "Read" >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
            | "Split" >> FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r"[A-Za-z\']+", x))
            | "Log" >> Map(lambda x: logging.info(f"x: {x}"))
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Running locally with direct runner yields,

```
...
INFO:root:x: his
INFO:root:x: enemy
INFO:root:x: king
INFO:root:x: and
INFO:root:x: did
INFO:root:x: him
...
```

While running on Google Cloud Dataflow yields nothing.
[image]

[image]

Here is the dependencies,

```
python = "^3.8"
apache-beam = {extras = ["gcp"], version = "^2.28.0"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out that the default sink in Logs Router exclude the Dataflow log.

Creating a new sink in Logs Router with inclusion filter of `resource.type="dataflow_step"` fixes the problem.

Comment: Even doing so and also checking the IAM roles, it didn't work. Curious is that the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#python_1) show an example of it and looks so easy (no config involved for basic `logging` usage)